# integration private messaging in laravel app

Tags: angular, laravel, single-page-application, private-messaging

I am looking for a solution for instant messaging, when only authenticated users can send instant message to other user with in this app.

I read many out many suggest nodejs socket io, but how we share session between laravel and node. Though i am intending to build token based authentication using passport and my client side will be angular full SPA.

I want to build in a way so that i can implement features of Progressive web app, so that i would not have to build separate mobile app.

another concern is how to make it SEO freindly, with earlier SPA development with angular6 and laravel i donot find any way to prerender application.

MY intention is to build basic rest api, that can be integrated with angular 6 SPA(authentication will be token based). and integrate private messaging so one authenticated user can send instant message to other with in my application

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a recently added package that could help you: beyondcode/laravel-websockets

You wont need to use node or anything outside laravel and this package.
Hope it helps :)

laravel approved! https://laravel-news.com/laravel-websockets

docs: https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/